# Javascript button to activate the method of apex class directly

Tags: apex

I have a javascript button on my product layout named "ListToEbay" and I have written a controller to invoke the EndItem()  service method of ebay api.

Below is the method:--

```
public void  removeItemFromEbayList() {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  Http http = new Http();
  sEnvelopHandlerForEndingList='Request XML';
  req.setBody(sEnvelopHandlerForEndingList);
}
```

I want to execute this method directly on clicking that button, without going or opening a `VisualForce Page`. How can I accomplish that?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

You have to make use of AJAX toolkit to call the method in Apex Controller.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
//sforce.apex.execute("classname","methodname","parameters seperated by comma");
sforce.apex.execute("classname","removeItemFromEbayList");
```

The consideration for this is that the `class` and the `methods` should be `global` and `webservice`. so you should modify the access modifier in your `class` to `global` and `method` from `public` to `webservice`.

Comment: Thanks for  reply.i am implementing it now and will come down with the result.

Comment: Updated the access modifiers for the class and method.

Comment: @VigneshwaranG Do these apex method invocations from javaacript also counted as callout?

Comment: @javanoob Yes. It is counted as callout.

Comment: @crmevengelist How is the implementation result coming up. Any positive outcome?

Answer (score 2):

If im not mistaken, the function should be define as webservice (global is not enough for the method), as follows :

```
    webservice void  removeItemFromEbayList(){...}
```

And note that it will count against an API call.