# Call Public class method from onclick javascript

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button, onclick, public

I have a public emailing apex class I need to call that from onclick javascript button of a detail page. Can someone let me know , if I can do that? Please give me an example. I am not getting it.

I have a global webservice method that receives List of an Sobject record.

**Apex webservice method**

```
webservice static void sendMails(List<Form_Requests_abv__c> newrequests)
    {
        Set<Id> formIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Form_Requests_abv__c  fr : newrequests) 
        {  
            formIds.add(fr.id);
        }

        List<String> sendtoemail = new List<String>();        

        List<ABV_Form_Request_abv__c>  Useremails= ABV_Form_Request_abv__c.getAll().values();
        if(!Useremails.isEmpty()){
           for(ABV_Form_Request_abv__c Useremail : Useremails)
           {
               if(String.isnotBlank(Useremail.Email_abv__c)){
...............
```

How can I pass value there?

**My javascript code**

```
var leadIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Form_Requests_abv__c)}; 
sforce.apex.execute("MailerUtils","sendMails",{newrequests: leadIds});
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: Does that detail page have a controller, or is it a standard view? Because you can call public methods on a controller in javascript with `<apex:actionFunction>`

Answer (score 2):

The input to the webservice is passed as a serialized `JSON` string.

You need to accept a string as input to the webservice method and deserialize it in the method.

So the definition of the webservice would be:

```
webservice static void sendMails(String newrequests){
```

To get the list, you would do this:

```
List<Form_Requests_abv__c> = (List<Form_Requests_abv__c>)JSON.deserialize(newrequests,List<Form_Requests_abv__c>.class);
```

The rest of your method can then be used as-is.

Comment: It gives  this error - unexpected token: 'List'

Comment: I am putting the code like this.                               webservice static void sendMails(String newrequests)
    {  
    List<Form_Requests_abv__c> = (List<Form_Requests_abv__c>)JSON.deserialize(newrequests,List<Form_Requests_abv__c>.class);
        //List<Form_Requests_abv__c> newrequests 
        Set<Id> formIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Form_Requests_abv__c  fr : newrequests) 
        {  
            formIds.add(fr.id);

Comment: I have implemented your changes but it shows - No operation found for the class. Please check WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91456/javascript-button-to-activate-the-method-of-apex-class-directly), your `class` and `methods` should be `global` and `webservice`.

Comment: Please find my question updated. If not using Public class I have a global class but need to pass List of the particular Sobject

Comment: Please see my code snippets.

Comment: Have you tried `Id`/`Set<Id>`/`List<Id>`?