# How to call a public method in javscript itself?

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

I have a custom button on my `Account` detail page called `Change`. I need to call a `public` method which is in a `public with sharing class`. What I have learned is that we can access the method using `sforce.apex.execute` if and only if the method is `web service` of a `global class`.

Comment: You can declare the method as remote action and then call it from your page.https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_summary.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have already answered your own question. You can only call `Apex` from a `Javascript Button` if your class is `global` and your method is `webservice`. This question already has an answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91456/javascript-button-to-activate-the-method-of-apex-class-directly).

I can certainly understand a reluctance to go `global`. Your alternative, if you would like to execute your `Apex` methods while leaving them `public`, is to instead make a `Visualforce` button and call the methods from a controller extension.

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountChangeExtension"
    action="{!executeApex}" />
```

**Extension**

```
public with sharing class AccountChangeExtension
{
    final Account record;
    final PageReference view;
    public AccountChangeExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        record = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        view = controller.view();
    }
    public PageReference executeApex()
    {
        AccountServices.doSomething(record);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
public with sharing class AccountServices
{
    public static void doSomething(Account record) { }
}
```